# Adding Brotli pre-compressed files as response body in ASP .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, compression, brotli

I have a static pre-compressed JS file with Brotli in ASP .NET Core 3.1. 
I want when a request for that file arrives ending with .js, to return the content of the pre-compressed version which is with the same name, ending with .js.br.

I tried adding some middleware code:

```
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = async (staticFilesContext) =>
    {
        IHeaderDictionary headers = staticFilesContext.Context.Response.Headers;
        var httpContext = staticFilesContext.Context;
        string contentType = headers["Content-Type"];

        if (contentType == "application/javascript" && staticFilesContext.File.Name.EndsWith("somehash.chunk.js"))
        {
            var compressed = @$"ClientApp\build\static\js\{staticFilesContext.File.Name}";

            var compressedBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(compressed);
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "br");
            await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(compressedBytes);
        }
    }
});
```

I tried 2 npm libraries for the pre-compression:

- [brotli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli) - with that one I got decoding error in Chrome console
- [brotli-max](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli-max) - the one I'm currently with, for which I receive the below error.

With that code, I get **net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR** response in Chrome. Sometimes I get exception in Visual Studio 2019 for content length:

> Response Content-Length mismatch: too many bytes written

How to properly write such a pre-compressed file as response? **I'm doing pre-compression, because I'm using level 11 of Brotli which is the slowest, so dynamic compression is not an option for me.**